# Learning python flask for the first time and I'm having a trouble connecting my React frontend with Flask Api

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, redux

I'm currently learning flask for the first time by making a simple API with it. I wrote my frontend with React JS and I made a simple visitor counter for my portfolio website.

The error that I'm getting right now is this:

**"TypeError: total_visitors() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, list, tuple with headers or status, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a function."**

Here's my React "home" component that is having a problem:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BsGithub } from "react-icons/bs";
import { BsLinkedin } from "react-icons/bs";
import { Link } from "react-scroll";
import { FaMedium } from "react-icons/fa6";
import Clock from "./clock";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import MyPic from "../images/mypic.jpg";
import { fetchVisitors, incrementVisitor } from "../features/counter/counterSlice";

export default function Home() {
  // const visitorCount = useSelector((state) => state.counter.value);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  

  useEffect(() => {
  
    dispatch(incrementVisitor()).then((action)=>{
      dispatch(fetchVisitors(action.payload))
    })
    
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="home-component" name="home">
      <div className="hero min-h-screen bg-base-600">
        <div className="hero-content text-center">
          <div className="max-w-md">
            <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold m-5">Hello there!</h1>
            <img
              src={MyPic}
              alt="me"
              className="w-20 rounded-full m-auto"
            ></img>

            <p className="py-6 text-lg">My name is Yoonsung Kim.</p>

            <div className="link-container">
              <nav className="flex">
                <a
                  href="https://github.com/jeffkim1118"
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noreferrer"
                  className="m-auto hover:animate-bounce"
                >
                  <BsGithub className="text-4xl m-auto" />
                  Github
                </a>

                <a
                  href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/yoonsung-kim-639b30178/"
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noreferrer"
                  className="m-auto hover:animate-bounce"
                >
                  <BsLinkedin className="text-4xl m-auto" />
                  Linkedin
                </a>

                <a
                  href="https://medium.com/@1019yskim"
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noreferrer"
                  className="m-auto hover:animate-bounce"
                >
                  <FaMedium className="text-4xl m-auto" />
                  Medium
                </a>
              </nav>
            </div>

            <div className="stats shadow m-3">
              <div className="stat">
                <Clock />
                <div className="stat-title">Total Page Views</div>
                <div className="stat-value" data-testid="hitcounter">
                  1000
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />

            <Link
              className="btn btn-primary"
              to="about"
              smooth={true}
              duration={600}
            >
              Get Started
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I use react-redux for the state management and I want to make all API requests inside of redux. Here's my counterSlice.js file:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const fetchVisitors = createAsyncThunk('fetchVisitors', async(values, thunkAPI) => {
    await fetch('http://localhost:5000/visitor')
    .then((res) => {res.json()})
    .then((data) => {return data})
    .catch((error) => {
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.value);
    });
    
});

export const incrementVisitor = createAsyncThunk('incrementVisitor', async(values, thunkAPI) => {
    await fetch('http://localhost:5000/visitor', {
        method:"POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body:JSON.stringify({value:values})
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {return data})
    .catch((error) => {
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.message);
    })
})

const counterSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'visitor-counter',
    initialState: {
        value: 0,
    },
    
    reducers:{
        increment:(state, action) => {
            state.value = action.payload;
        },
        getVisitors: (state,action) => {
            state.value = action.payload
        }
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
        .addCase(fetchVisitors.fulfilled,(state,action) => {
            state.value = action.payload;
        })
        .addCase(incrementVisitor.fulfilled, (state,action) => {
            state.value = action.payload + 1;
        })
    }
    
})
export const { increment, getVisitors } = counterSlice.actions;
export default counterSlice.reducer
```

And here's my flask api.py:

```
import time
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')

total_visitors = {
    'counter':0
}

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, world</p>"

@app.route('/time')
def get_current_time():
    return {'time': time.time()}

@app.route('/visitor', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin()
def total_visitors():
    global total_visitors
    if request.method == "POST":
        total_visitors.counter+=1
        return total_visitors
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return total_visitors
```

I want to make sure I get the number of total visitors and increment the number of total visitors using a get and a post request from my redux to display it in my React frontend.
I might have made a lot of mistakes in my code so, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your error says:

> The return type must be a string, dict, list, tuple with headers or status, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a function.

You have declared a variable with the same name as your method name and when you typed return `total_visitors`, the function is being returned instead of the variable. Change your variable name to something else.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I just realized that one of my function name is same as the total_visitors variable. The error message is gone but, I still can't get any data from my API from the frontend and there's no error message shown...

Comment: Im not very good at react, but I can see that after hitting the /visitors endpoint, you are not returning the `res.json()`. Could it probably be because of that?

Comment: I don't think that's the reason because I'm returning "data" which refers to "res.json()"